# Get ContentControl Control's Template Children?

Tags: silverlight, templates, contentcontrol

We're working on a Silverlight application that uses a generic custom ContentControl. This ContentControl has a Control Template specified in a Generic.xaml.

The inherited ContentControl's Template...

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExtContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExtContentControl">
                <Border x:Name="content" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Child="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The inherited ComboBox's Template...

```
<controltemplate targettype="local:ExtComboBox"></controltemplate>
```

...

```
<Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
```

When it is instantiated the ContentControl's content is set to a (generic) control which can be a Textbox, Dropdown, Label or Datepicker.

```
public class ExtContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public ExtContentControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExtContentControl);

        RenderControl();
    }

    private void RenderControl()
    {
        ExtComboBox extComboBox = new ExtComboBox();
        this.Content = extComboBox;
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Border bor = GetTemplateChild("content") as Border;

        ExtComboBox cmbTest = bor.Child as ExtComboBox;

        //Find FocusVisualElement from ExtComboBox Control Template
        //Rectangle rec = cmbTest.FindName("FocusVisualElement") as Rectangle;
        //cmbTest returns null
    }
}
```

As you can see in my last comment...

//Find FocusVisualElement from ExtComboBox Control Template
//Rectangle rec = cmbTest.FindName("FocusVisualElement") as Rectangle;
//cmbTest returns null

How can I get hold of FocusVisualElement from inside OnApplyTemplate inside the ContentControl?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I would inherit the TextBox and add two dependency properties. Then it won't be difficult to retrieve necessary values.

Comment: Similar question to this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125641/get-nested-control-located-in-controltemplate-in-code-behind

Answer (score 1):

Solution for this...

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/192431/Hover-Foreground-Colour-with-dynamic-binding-Conte.aspx

Comment: An easier way to do this is to import System.Windows.Controls.Primitives and use the VisualTreeHelper Extensions GetVisualDescendants or GetVisualAncestors!

e.g.: 

`protected override OnApplyTemplate()
{
base.OnApplyTemplate();
Border bor = GetVisualDescendants().OfType<Border>().FirstOrDefault(x => (x as FrameworkElement).Name == "content"); };`