# Access children from contextmenu control template c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I am trying to access a control from a control's context menu's control template.My xaml is :

```
 <Button x:Name="button1" ContextMenuService.Placement="top" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,543,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="btconmn" >
                <ContextMenu.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="newgrid"  Width="183" Height="190">
                            <Rectangle Fill="#FF263349" x:Name="newfolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Height="32" Margin="2,1,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.Template>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

Here i'm trying to access the `newfolder` rectangle. So far i tried :

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    var template = btconmn.Template;
    var myControl = (Rectangle)template.FindName("newfolder", btconmn);
 }
```

which returns a null reference exception.Any help ?

Comment: Where exactly do you override `OnApplyTemplate`? Since you don't have a custom class in your code I'm guessing in the wrong spot.

Comment: it's in the main class/window class.

Comment: i know i'm doing it wrong somewhere but can't figure out where..I actually followed this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911344/get-contentcontrol-controls-template-children

Comment: `OnApplyTemplate()` is something you would usually only use in the control itself (custom control). What are you trying to do with the rectangle?

Comment: Never mind my motive but u said `use in the control itself`,does this mean if i added he code to a class which inherits the control,it would've worked then ?

Comment: andhey bro, don't downvote my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48968100/no-imaging-component-suitable-to-complete-this-operation-was-found-wpf-c-sharp/48970823?noredirect=1#comment84958139_48970823) but a comment says that my code(in answer) is horrible..Can u please explain why ?

Comment: If you write a custom class that inherits from `ContextMenu`, then yes - that would be the best place to do so, but then you should also add a TemplatePartAttribute (`[TemplatePart("newfolder")]`) to that class.

Comment: Probably because you are mixing WPF (DirectX) and WindowForms (GDI+) classes which is quite unnecessary (And when Clemens tells you that you are doing something wrong in WPF - then you are doing something wrong, he knows what he is talking about)

Comment: seems like u know CLEMENS very well ?

Comment: But anyways, it's a reat pleasure to learn from u guys ! :)

Comment: Not personally, but I've answered/discussed the same questions occasionally and so far I always agreed with what he said/wrote. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF controls usually don't load until they are needed, so in your case the earliest point at which you can access the rectangle would be **after** the button's contextmenu is loaded (which happens immediately before it opens for the first time):

Add this to your XAML:

```xaml
<ContextMenu x:Name="btconmn" Loaded="Btconmn_OnLoaded">
```

And this in your code behind:

```cs
private void Btconmn_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var template = btconmn.Template;
    var myControl = (Rectangle)template.FindName("newfolder", btconmn);
}
```

Comment: I am glad that ur code worked.I knew `after the button's contextmenu is loaded` and that's why i tried to apply the code to the `opened` event of the contextmenu.Why didn't work then ? I thought that maybe the `opened` event fires immedietly when th econtextmenu is opened . That's why i applied the code to the `close` event as well, but none of 'em worked ....why so ?

Comment: The `opened` event probably fires *before* the entire visual tree is done loading and `closed` *after* it has been unloaded again.

Comment: Is it possible to apply an animation(storyboard) to the contextmenu ? Usually it pops up which seems like it's opacity changes from 0 to 1...any way to change that ?

Comment: @F.raiyan Probably, [this seems promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160467/how-to-disable-wpf-contextmenu-animations) - but we are moving a bit out-of-scope with this question now.